# SQL select 2 tables but not ommit blank results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to do a select from 3 trables.

```
table1- idc,title,description..

table2- idc,filename,filepath,tabel1FK

table3- idc,table1FK,tabel2FK
```

I need a select from table1 and table2 and count unique ocurrences of table1 in table3

the select must be something like this

```
TB1 | TB2 | COUNT ON TB3

  a |  aa  | 1
  b |      | 4 
  c |  cc  | 3 
  d |      | 0 
  e |      | 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want `left join` and `group by`:

```
select tb1.idc, tb2.idc, count(tb3.idc)
from tb1 left join
     tb2
     on tb2.table1FK = tb1.idc left join
     tb3
     on tb3.table1FK = tb1.idc and tb3.tabel2FK = tb2.idc
group by tb1.idc, tb2.idc;
```